# Dynamic generation of TCP client with inbound channel and respond channel

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm new to Spring integration.

Working with Spring 4, Only java anotations.

The project where i'm working now we set up tcp connection in a property file.

At the momet it is hardcoded to only 2 different connections and it must be changed to a more dynamic approach where we can set up a variable amount of them in the property file and be able to add new ones at runtime.

I'm aware of the existence of [dynamic tcp client example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client) and tried to base my work on it.

First we set up the following bean for the connection:

```
@Bean(name = "node1TCPConnection")
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory node1TCPConnection() {
  final TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpNetClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(
  env.getProperty("socket.tcp.nodes[0].ip"), 
  env.getProperty("socket.tcp.nodes[0].port", Integer.class)
  );

  tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
  tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);

  final ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer by = new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(headBytes);

  tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSerializer(by);
  tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(by);
  return tcpNetClientConnectionFactory;
}
```

Then we have the adapter who waits for something to sent:

```
@Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter node1TcpReaderClient(
        @Qualifier("node1TCPConnection") final AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
    adapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    adapter.setClientMode(true);
    adapter.setErrorChannelName("errorChannel");
    adapter.setRetryInterval(retryInterval);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(fromTcp());
    return adapter;
}
```

When fromTcp() is called it transforms the message and the following code sends it to another application for further processing.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp")
public void outbound(final String inMessage, final @Headers Map<String, Object> headerMap) {
    sendToApi(inMessage, headerMap);
}
```

When the message is procesed we have to send a response.

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcpCh01")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOutGateCh01(
        final @Qualifier("node1TCPConnection") AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpSendingMsgHandler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    tcpSendingMsgHandler.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return tcpSendingMsgHandler;
}
```

and by using a gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway()
public interface MessageTcpGateway {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "toTcpCh01")
  ListenableFuture<Void> sendTcpChannel01(@Header("host") String host, byte[] inMessage);
}
```

we send it back.

With the example I can understand how to dynamically create a flow for the response.

But I can't fathom how to create a common connection pool and then create listening adapters and response adapters on the fly based on those connectionsfactory and then closing/removing them on runtime.

I somewhat understand how to make a flow with an inbound adapter thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778491/dynamic-tcp-server-with-spring-integration-using-java-dsl?newreg=ee10ac5373c94e549a2d1456f9585233)

Do I need to create multiple separate IntegrationFlow for each adapter? so all the calls and responses can be handled asynchronous ( I may be wrong about the asynchrony)

and then handle them separatly when wanting to close a connection? like calling close to the TcpReceivingChannelAdapter and then to TcpSendingMessageHandler  and finally deregistering the connectonfactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't this that for [Collaborating Channel Adapters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#_collaborating_outbound_and_inbound_channel_adapters) you need separate `IntegrationFlow` definitions for the `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` and `TcpSendingMessageHandler`. It really can be done as a single `IntegrationFlow` starting from the `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` and ending with the `TcpSendingMessageHandler`. The point is that `IntegrationFlow` per se is just a logical container to group components references. The hard work is really done by all those components you declare there and with this `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` to `TcpSendingMessageHandler` and gateway in between you are really going to be async.

Please, keep in mind that `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` has to be declared as a bean as well. Not sure that you need a separate instance for each dynamic flow, but here is an API to do that from there anyway:

```
    /**
     * Add an object which will be registered as an {@link IntegrationFlow} dependant bean in the
     * application context. Usually it is some support component, which needs an application context.
     * For example dynamically created connection factories or header mappers for AMQP, JMS, TCP etc.
     * @param bean an additional arbitrary bean to register into the application context.
     * @return the current builder instance
     */
    IntegrationFlowRegistrationBuilder addBean(Object bean);
```

Comment: Are you saying that I need to register all the components as beans?
Or at least the TcpNetClientConnectionFactory and TcpReceivingChannelAdapter?

And to close them should I close the adapters first and then the connectionFactory next?

Comment: No, I only talk about `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` as a bean. Everything else is indeed registered as beans in application context automatically by the `IntegrationFlow` processor. You don't need to close anything manually - the `IntegrationFlow` is enough. It will propagate close to all its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, and a last aclaration. should i register them both this way?
this.flowContext.registration(inflow).addBean(cf).id(hostPort + ".in").register();
this.flowContext.registration(outflow).addBean(cf).id(hostPort + ".out").register();

or should i register the bean only once in one?

Comment: No, you need to register that `cf` only once since you really need the same instance for both `inbound` and `outbound` flows.